# How to simplify a diabolical expression involving radicals

Tags: fractions, radicals

A friend and I have been working on this problem for hours - how can the following expression be simplified analytically?

It equals $\frac{1}{2},$ and we have tried the following to no avail:

1. Substitution of $x = \sqrt{5}$
2. Substitution of $x = 2\sqrt{5}$
3. Substitution of $x = 5+\sqrt{5}$
4. Substitution of $x = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5}}$
5. Manipulations by substituting the golden ratio

Here goes:
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt{5}}}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{5(5 + 2\sqrt{5})}}{4} - \dfrac{\sqrt{10 + 2\sqrt{5}}}{8}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{5(5 + 2\sqrt{5})}}{4} + 5 \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt{5}}}{4}}$$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not guaranteed to work, but it's where I'd start: have you plugged it into [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com)?

Comment: Yes - that's how we got the $\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Hint, say that $\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}{4}}=x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\ a = \sqrt{5+2\sqrt 5},\ b = \sqrt{10+2\sqrt 5}.\,$  Show $\,\color{#c00}{b = (\sqrt5 -1) a},\,$ so scaling the top and bottom of the fraction by $\,8\,$ yields $\ \dfrac{4a+ 2\sqrt 5 a - \color{#c00}{(\sqrt5 -1) a}}{10a + 2\sqrt 5 a}^{\phantom{1^{1^1}}}\!\!\!\!\!\! =\, \dfrac{1}2$

Comment: **Hint 2** $\, $ To show the $\rm\color{#c00}{equality}$ it suffices to show its square (using positivity).